# No proper resolution settings on my ASUS x53s (Nvidia/Intel)

Tags: resolution, hdmi, nvidia-optimus

I have an ASUS x53s on which I've installed Ubuntu 10.11. I have read several threads about the Optimus feature using dual GPUs (integrated Intel and dedicated Nvidia) and I have also installed both bumblebee and the proprietary Nvidia driver but still I am not able to neither run nvidia-config or having a proper resolution setting menu. Any suggestions?

The resolution I have is 1366 x 768 (16:9) and it is "fixed", i.e. I have no other options to set, and this goes for the case when I don't have an external display connected as well. I tagged it as hdmi since this is the interface used for my external display and there I would need to be able to set a higher resolution, else the output is quite poor.

Comment: `nvidia-xconfig` should not be used for generating `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` for the default display, it breaks stuff like 3D acceleration. What is the maximum resolution that you can set? I see this question tagged as `hdmi`, are you talking about an external screen?

Comment: The resolution I have is 1366 x 768 (16:9) and it is "fixed", i.e. I have no other options to set, and this goes for the case when I don't have an external display connected as well.

I tagged it as hdmi since this is the interface used for my external display and there I would need to be able to set a higher resolution, else the output is quite poor.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!